# Add API method for network-wide search

Tags: feature-request, api, search

Just like stackexchange.com has a [networkwide search](https://stackexchange.com/search), it would be nice to have an equivalent of [`excerpt-search`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/excerpt-search) which searches the entire network at once. That would save me 360 calls (per-site metas are indexed too) in some situations.